# Should equipment comparison questions be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, questions

Can an equipment comparison question have an objective answer? Can we make a blanket ruling on these or will it depend on how the questions are worded?

Some examples:

- Should I use glass carboys or better bottles?
- Which is better for mashing, a beverage cooler or a chest cooler?
- What is the best fridge for making a kegerator?

Answer (score 10):

Opinions and experience make up a large part of brewing I think. To rule them out would hurt the site.

Comment: How do we keep the discussions from being too subjective or argumentative?

Comment: @Nicholas Trandem: By following the "Guidelines" of Good Subjective, Bad Subjective: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 9):

I think that questions that ask for "what is best" should be voted down. But I think that questions asking for pros and cons on equipment should be allowed.

For example.

"What's best? Glass or plastic carboys?"

vote down because you'll inevitably get answers like "Plastic sucks only use glass"

vs.

"What are the pros and cons of using plastic carboys instead of glass"

Vote up because you will get good answers with subjective information such as...

"Plastic carboys are a good alternative to glass as they are light-weight and inexpensive. The downside to them is that they scratch more easily and can harbor bacteria that can infect your beer."

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to brew the same beer, and being able to ask about the pros/cons of different equipment should be allowed.